# Series of product of legendre polynomials with shifted degree

Tags: power-series, generating-functions, quantum-mechanics, legendre-polynomials, hadamard-product

I am working on some quantum mechanics and I would love to find a closed expression for the series
$$
S(x,y) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty P_l(x) P_{l+1}(y)
$$
$x,y \in \left[ -1, 1\right]$ and also for its multisection
$$
S_{qp}(x,y) = \sum_{l=0}^\infty P_{lq+p}(x) P_{lq+p+1}(y)
$$
where $q \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $p < q$ and $P_l$ is the $l$-th legendre polynomial.

The first series is a special case of a Hadamard product of two generating functions $F(x,t) \odot G(y,t)$
\begin{align}
F(x,t) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2xt + t^2}} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty P_l(x) t^l\\
G(y,t) &= \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2yt + t^2}} - 1 \right)= \sum_{l=0}^\infty P_{l+1}(y) t^l \; \text{.}
\end{align}
for $t=1$. Having the generating function for $F(x,t) \odot G(y,t)$ we would also have the multisection generating function, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Extracting_arithmetic_progressions_of_a_sequence).

There is a way to compute the [Hadamard product via an integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Hadamard_products_and_diagonal_generating_functions) but I am not sure how (and whether) I can use this formula because it probably works only for $F$, $G$ being rational functions (a proof is here [Derivation of the termwise Hadamard product of two generating functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3526636/derivation-of-the-termwise-hadamard-product-of-two-generating-functions)). I think the integral diverges in general.

I did some numerical calculations and it seems the expression shouldn't be so complicated. On [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4eyD.png) is $S(x,y)$ with $x=1/2$ and $y$ being the $x$ axis. As $x$ moves, the point of discontinuity shifts, it is always at $y=x$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting problem! Indeed the graph of $S$ looks like it admits quite some structure; the simple mathematica code `f[x_, y_, nmax_] := 
 Sum[LegendreP[n, x]*LegendreP[n + 1, y], {n, 0, nmax}]
Plot3D[f[x, y, 600], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` produced the following images: [1](https://i.postimg.cc/Qd2GSpsk/grafik.png) [2](https://i.postimg.cc/NjTPsZqm/grafik.png) [3](https://i.postimg.cc/WbzBv91w/grafik.png). While I think the bends at $(-1,1),(1,-1)$ are truncation artifacts, I'm not so sure the same is true at $(-1,-1),(1,1)$

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde For $y=1$ the function is just $S(x,1) = 1/ \sqrt{2 - 2x}$ (it's the F generating function) and we see that the bends at $(-1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$ are indeed just a numerical error, the real value there is $1/2$ at $(-1,1)$ and $-1/2$ at $(1,-1)$. From the same reason the value at $(1,1)$ is diverging to $+ \infty$ and value at $(-1-1)$ to $- \infty$ (because $P_l(-1)  P_{l+1}(-1) = -1$) . I am not sure whether all the values at $x=y$ are diverging but my guess is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, for $t\in \left[ -1,1\right]$,

$$\sum_{l=0}^\infty P_l(\cos\alpha) P_{l+1}(\cos\beta) t^l \!=\! \frac{2 \left(e^{-i \alpha } K\left(\frac{4 t \sin\alpha \sin\beta}{1-2 t\cos (\alpha +\beta )+t^2}\right)+\left(e^{-i \beta } t-e^{-i
   \alpha }\right) \Pi \left(\frac{2 i t \sin\beta }{e^{i \beta } t-e^{-i \alpha }}\bigg{|}\frac{4 t \sin\alpha \sin\beta}{1-2t\cos (\alpha
   +\beta)+t^2}\right)\right)}{\pi  t \sqrt{1-2 t \cos (\alpha +\beta )+t^2}},$$

where $$K(m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\sqrt{1-m \sin^2 \varphi}}, \qquad \Pi(n|m) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{(1-n \sin^2 \varphi)\sqrt{1-m \sin^2 \varphi}}$$ are complete elliptic integrals of the first and the third kind, respectively.

Note that this result always turns out to be real. The first argument $n$ of $\Pi$ is complex, but there might be formulae for $\Pi$ expressing it in real arguments only.